# Getting an error for " bad operand types for binary operator '/'" using scanner :(

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PACE
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int walkTime = 0;
 
        System.out.println("Enter Food: ");
        String food = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter calories: ");
        String calories = keyboard.nextLine();

        walkTime = calories / 5.2;
         
        System.out.println("Your must walk: "+ walkTime +" minutes.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Comment: What is the result of `"Hello World" / 5.2` and why do you believe it even has a valid result? `calories` is a `String`, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a strongly typed language: `calories` is a string and can not be divided as an integer.

To make calories an integer, use the following method:

```
int calories = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to make calories an int and put int in front of the formula

```
     System.out.println("Enter calories: ");
     int calories = keyboard.nextInt();
     
     walkTime = (int)(calories / 5.2);
```